# Merge two pandas dataframe by looking multi column fields based on text similarity

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, spacy, data-cleaning

I have a dirty dataframe d (top one) and reference dataframe r consists of following fields

[image]

d dataframe have misspelled author names, publishers, book names sometimes only one field is misspelled  sometimes multiple fields. I want to match d rows with r rows with a similarity confidence level with a new row which book name , author and publisher must be similar. Which NLP method should I need to use? Can you give a hint? I am new to data science and ML.

Comment: probably best to do a fuzzy match on the`book_name` can you provide your data as text [mcve] as well as what youv'e tried ? others will surely be able to help you then.

Comment: fuzzy match is the key word I was searching I am looking FuzzyWuzzy python package now. I hope I will post my own answer when it is ready. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare a value in one dataframe to a column in another using fuzzywuzzy ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312265/how-to-compare-a-value-in-one-dataframe-to-a-column-in-another-using-fuzzywuzzy)